# Runtime crash of ROS2 talker due to struct representations in C and C++ with clang

Tags: ros, ros2, talker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[I've modified this question into more of an explanation, because the issue appears to be in my compiler, rather than with ROS2; however, it's an interesting trace through what I think happens when you call `rclcpp::init()`, so I thought I'd leave it up.]

I'm trying to run a simple ROS2 (dashing) talker demo on a research system that closely tracks pointer provenance.  The system crashes at runtime with a trace that says I'm trying to execute data on the stack.

If I follow the trace, I end up in rcl init_options.c, trying to allocate with a non-existent allocator.  Here is the trace from the main function:

from `talker.cpp` main:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    ...
}
```

`rclcpp::init` is in in `utilities.cpp`:

```
void init(int argc, char const * const argv[], const InitOptions & init_options)
{
  using contexts::default_context::get_global_default_context;
  get_global_default_context()->init(argc, argv, init_options);
  ...
}
```

`init` expects three arguments, but we only provide two (`argc` and `argv`).

The prototype for `rclcpp::init` (in `utilities.hpp`) deals with this, as it has a default:

```
void init(int argc, char const * const argv[], const InitOptions & init_options = InitOptions());
```

`InitOptions()` is prototyped in `init_options.hpp` as:

```
explicit InitOptions(rcl_allocator_t allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator())
```

`rcl_get_default_allocator()` is in `rcl`s `allocator.h`:

```
#define rcl_get_default_allocator rcutils_get_default_allocator
```

which takes us to `rcutils` `allocator.c`, which is where things get interesting:

```
rcutils_allocator_t rcutils_get_default_allocator()
{
    static rcutils_allocator_t default_allocator = {
        .allocate = __default allocate,
        ...
        .state = NULL,
    };
    return default_allocator;
}
```

So this assigns the function `__default_allocate()` as the `allocate` function of the default `allocator`.  `__default_allocate()` is also `rcutils` `allocator.c`:

```
static void *
__default _allocate(size_t size, void * state)
{
    RCUTILS_UNUSED(state);
    return malloc(size);
}
```

So now we have a default `allocator`, which is provided to `rclcpp::InitOptions` as part of the call to `rclcpp::init` shown above.

```
InitOptions::InitOptions(rcl_allocator_t allocator)
: init_options_(new rcl_init_options_t)
{
  *init_options_ = rcl_get_zero_initialized_init_options();
  rcl_ret_t ret = rcl_init_options_init(init_options_.get(), allocator);
  if (RCL_RET_OK != ret) {
    rclcpp::exceptions::throw_from_rcl_error(ret, "failed to initialized rcl init options");
  }
}
```

`InitOptions` takes the default `allocator` and passes it to `rcl_init_options_init()` in `rcl`s `init_options.c`.

<<< C++ calling C with a structure >>>

```
rcl_init_options_init(rcl_init_options_t * init_options, rcl_allocator_t allocator)
{
  RCL_CHECK_ARGUMENT_FOR_NULL(init_options, RCL_RET_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
  if (NULL != init_options->impl) {
    RCL_SET_ERROR_MSG("given init_options (rcl_init_options_t) is already initialized");
    return RCL_RET_ALREADY_INIT;
  }
  RCL_CHECK_ALLOCATOR(&allocator, return RCL_RET_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
  init_options->impl = allocator.allocate(sizeof(rcl_init_options_impl_t), allocator.state);
  ...
}
```

Here, it finally crashes when trying to call `allocator.allocate()`.

This appears to be because our version of `clang` has different conventions for passing structures as arguments to functions.  For C++, it appears to load a pointer to the whole structure into a register.  For C, it appears to load the structure members.  Therefore, when `rcl_init_options_init()` (a C function) calls `allocator.allocate()`, which was provided by `InitOptions()` (a C++ constructor), it doesn't find what it expects in memory and crashes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348954/runtime-crash-of-ros2-talker-due-to-struct-representations-in-c-and-c++-with-clang/) by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) on 2020-04-09**:
[Update]  Before anyone spends any time on this:  This appears to be a compiler issue with our version of Clang.  We've patched it and I'm currently rebuilding everything.  If it works, I'll close this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've modified this question into more of an explanation, because the issue appears to be in my compiler, rather than with ROS2; however, it's an interesting trace through what I think happens when you call `rclcpp::init()`, so I thought I'd leave it up and close out the question.

---

Originally posted by [broomstick](https://answers.ros.org/users/50781/broomstick/) with karma: 111 on 2020-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0